# Scrolling table with tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a scrollable table from the first answer of this question. Like in the JS [here](http://jsbin.com/nolanole/1/edit?html,js,output).

In my case my scrollable table needs some tbody inside and when I add them the scroll doesn't work well when it reaches the end.

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/zifivaqowe/edit?html,css,output). At the end of the scroll, there is a space and it should not.

(I need `tbody` on each tr because I will make from tbody an angular component that will display several tr for row grouping).

Comment: I think "this question" should be a link.

Comment: Is it solved? I can't find any issues

Comment: the issue is first column row 9 is not align with the other columns when it scrolls to the end vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typo. You have an extra chracter at the end of the second table :

```
</table>`
```

After removing it, works fine.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/divimihumu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: where I don't see it. mybe could you send the corrected js bin? thx

Comment: I added the link.

Comment: It is apostrophe like characher. After </table> tag.

Comment: oh you are right. So small it appears like dust on my screen. By the way the example is not so good as the line 9 is not really align to the other columns. What could cause that

Comment: try :  <div id="firstcol" style="overflow: hidden;height:85px">

Comment: @user3409988 you can also reset box-sizing to have both to match http://jsbin.com/zifivaqowe/edit?html,css,js,output